# Determing if Linear Transformations are Isomorphic

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T: \mathbb{R^2} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ where $T\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix} = a-bi$ Determine whether or not the linear transformation is isomorphic

Workings:

The basis of $\mathbb{R^2}$ is $ \left \{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \right \}$

$\dim(\mathbb{R^2}) = 2$

The basis of $\mathbb{C}$ is $\{1,i\}$

$\dim(\mathbb{C}) = 2$

Since $\dim(\mathbb{R^2}) = \dim(\mathbb{C})$

$\mathbb{R^2}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$.

I'm not sure if I did this correctly.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: A language note: linear transformations are not isomorphic, they are isomorphisms.  A pair of spaces are isomorphic if there is an isomorphism between them.

Comment: As Michael Burr says, there is some linguistic confusion, but the question being asked is not whether $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are isomorphic as $\mathbb{R}$ vector spaces. Indeed, as you point out, they both has the same dimension over $\mathbb{R}$, and are hence isomorphic. However, I believe the question is asking whether the linear transformation given is an isomorphism. There are certainly linear transformations between isomorphic spaces which are not themselves isomorphisms.

Comment: @Alex Wertheim You are right I wrote the question wrong. It did say isomorphisms.

Comment: If it's linear and has an inverse defined for all vectors in the co-domain then it's an isomorphism. Easy to show in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, but very tentatively so.

The reason is that you are applying a derived out theorem that states that any two vector spaces with the same dimensions are *isomorphic*. This is markedly different than defining an explicit transformation between two algebraic structures known as an isomor*phism*.

The real proof of this must borrow from abstract algebra, in which case an isomorphism is defined as a function between two algebraic structures that is bijective (same sizes are established, injectivity established) and also a homomorphism (in other words, preserves structure).

All linear transformations are homomorphic on both operations on vector spaces, so the last remaining necessity is bijectibility. Dimension is intimately related to the concept of set cardinality. There can always exist a transformation that is linear between vector spaces. However, bijections only exist if the two vector spaces are of the same dimension. This is because we can describe a vector space entirely with just the basis set. If you define a linear transformation with respect to both basis sets, you will see that it's basically just the identity transformation if you align it with respect to the exact basis.